# "unsupported parameter" when mapping a stored procedure? (EF)

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that I return the new ID number. The code looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo]. [Save Contact]

@FirstName varchar (50),
@LastName varchar (50),
@Email varchar (50)
AS
BEGIN
- SET NOCOUNT ON added to Prevent extra result sets from
- Interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO Contacts (FirstName, LastName, Email)
VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @Email)

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as newid
END
```

When I try to map my stored procedures I get the following error:

> Error 1 Error 2047: A mapping function binding specifier a function demoModel.Store.SaveContact with an unsupported parameter: id. Output parameters May only be mapped through the RowsAffectedParameter property. Use result bindings to return values ​​from a function invocation.

[image]

Is there anyone here who can see what I'm doing wrong?

Need more code, let me know.

Comment: I don't see `id` in the SP parameters anywhere...

Comment: I have tried to add the ID but it gives the same result.

i can't update the post, but @newID int is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the SQL as it is above remove `id` as a parameter for the insert statement. Its not needed. To get `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` you only need to map `newid` it in the Result Column Bindings.

Also ensure that the column name in Result Column Bindings is the same case as the stored procedure is returning.

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/03/26/stored-procedure-mapping.aspx